# HTML: use one nav bar for multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

below i wanted to create one nav bar for multiple html pages for ease of use .. using JS it gives error ..it seems weird to me,also i wanted to use same method for footer as well

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/saad/Desktop/myhome-real-estate-free-web-template/navbar.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https`

```js
fetch('navbar.html')
.then(res => res.text())
.then(text => {
    let oldelem = document.querySelector("script#replace_with_navbar");
    let newelem = document.createElement("div");
    newelem.innerHTML = text;
    oldelem.parentNode.replaceChild(newelem,oldelem);
})
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div id="wrapper" class="home-page">

        <header>
            <div id="nav-placeholder">

            </div>
            
            <script>
            $(function(){
              $("#nav-placeholder").load("navbar.html");
            });
            </script>
        
        </header>
    
    </body>
```

and my navbar.html code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                 <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">About Us <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="about.html">Company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
                <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</html>
```

is there a way to solve this? cux i can't figure out the problem
thanks in advance

Comment: quick google search found this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp hope this helps

Comment: for the CORS issue, add option to the fetch request. 
`var config = {
 method: 'GET',
 headers: new Headers(),
mode: 'cors',
cache: 'default' };`
then, you can call fetch like this: `fetch('navbar.html', config)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your project through a web server. Opening a file in a browser through a file severely limits its capabilities.